# How should I choose the resistors in a voltage divider?

Tags: adc, voltage-divider

I would like to measure tree signals by using a ucontroller.

the signals are between

- -5V to 5V
- 0V to 2V
- -20V to 20V

The frequency of the signals are between 1MHz and 5MHz. 
The ADC range is between 0 and 3V.

I built the following simulation, where I am dividing and shifting the measured signal:
[image]

I have the following questions regarding the circuit:

- How should I choose the resistors in the voltage divider and OP-AMP gain?
- How can I make 'dynamic' voltage divider? I mean controlled by microcontroller? I checked the analog switches in the TI website but I am not really familiar with those switches.
- How can I protect the circuit from over voltages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The "*resistors in the voltage divider*" presumably refer to Resistor 6 and Resistor 7 in the schematic, providing the biased signal voltage to one of the inputs of the op-amp.

  - These dividers would be selected such that their combined resistance in parallel is significantly smaller than the input impedance of the op-amp. Otherwise, the current into the op-amp input will change the bias voltage - like putting an additional resistor of comparable value in parallel with one leg of the divider.
  - Also, they should be of high enough value that the current through them does not draw an unreasonable amount of current from DC Voltage Source 1.
  - Finally, the resistors should be of sufficient power rating to tolerate the power dissipation `P = I^2 x R` for the current drawn through them, `I = V(DC1) / (R1 + R2)`
- The op-amp gain resistors would depend on the gain desired. Since the schematic does not indicate inverting and non-inverting inputs, it is not clear (*at least to me*) whether this is intended as an inverting or non-inverting amplifier, and what the intention of that part of the design is.
- Dynamic voltage dividers can be implemented in a variety of ways, which include using a [digital potentiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_potentiometer) IC, an resistor array with switched legs, etc.

  - If one assumes that the question envisages only 3 possible input signal voltages, a dynamic voltage divider may not be needed. One could structure 3 voltage dividers, and switch the appropriate one in using a very small R<sub>ds(on)</sub> MOSFET, such that the MOSFET's resistance does not discernibly impact circuit behavior.
  - Just 2 voltage dividers would suffice, if the intention is merely to provide a counter-bias of -1 Volts for the 0-2 Volt signal when that is the source.
- Overvoltage protection (presumably referring to the input signal voltage) can be achieved by using a [voltage limiting zener diode circuit](http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee320/notes/320lecture9.pdf), at the simplest level.

  - Depending on the currents involved and the behavior desired, other solutions such as voltage foldback or SCR-based crowbar circuits may be called for - apparently not applicable in this case.